# How to develop a Chrome extension to provide an unread message count icon for Telegram?

Tags: google-chrome, telegram

I would like to develop a Chrome extension that provides an unread message count icon for Telegram.

1. Does someone know if the API of Telegram allow for this?
2. If yes, what are the basic steps involved to access the API and display the number of unread messages in a Chrome toolbar badge icon?

Comment: short answer - Yes indeed it is possible. I've never developed a chrome-extension, but i believe if you can host/ run javascript code in a chrome-extension, and also have access to some for of persistable storage - to store session, salt, and auth-keys, then you should be able to build a very basic, light weight javascript telegram client, and host it in your chrome-extension